# Am I vulnerable to SQL Injection?

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection, liquibase

I have this class that extends a class that implements CustomTaskChange. Since some of the class attributes like the column name and type are passed to it by a XML file, I need to make a string concatenation. I do use PreparedStatement, but I wonder if I am still vulnerable to SQL Injection because of it and if that is the case how can I make it safe?
The XML is a Liquibase ChangeSet (I will leave a sample below) .

### XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.8.xsd">
  <changeSet author="" id="57ba1e10-3e3a-4be1-a7a0-7a9fb9411565">
    <customChange class="com.petapilot.migrations.customChanges.MultipleAdd" columnName="testeRegex" columnType="varchar(250)"
    regex="saft_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{1,10}_[0-9]{1,10}_nc_transactions" after="CreditAmount" notNull="true" default="sbc"></customChange>
  </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

### Custom Class

```
@Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {

        try {
            //check if there are any errors in the changelog file
            checkArgumentsNumber();

            boolean tablesFound = false;
            boolean columnsAdded = false;
            String sqlStatement = "ALTER TABLE NAME ADD COLUMN " +this.getColumnName()+" "+this.getColumnType();

            if(notNull){
                sqlStatement+=" NOT NULL";
            }

            if(defaultValue!=null){
                sqlStatement+=" DEFAULT ?";
            }

            if (this.after != null) {
                sqlStatement += " AFTER " +this.after;
            }

            System.out.println("The statement is: "+sqlStatement);

            //get tables in the database
            JdbcConnection connection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
            DatabaseMetaData metadata;
            metadata = connection.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            ResultSet rs = metadata.getTables(connection.getCatalog(), null, "%", types);

            //if the user chose to use a regex
            if (this.getRegex() != null) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(this.getRegex());

                while (rs.next()) {
                    String tableName = rs.getString(3);
                    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tableName);
                    boolean matches = matcher.matches();
                    if (matches) {
                        tablesFound = true;
                        String addStatement=sqlStatement.replaceAll("NAME",tableName);
                        PreparedStatement s = connection.prepareStatement(addStatement);
                        if (!checkColumnsExists(s, tableName)) {
                            if(this.defaultValue!=null){
                                s.setString(1,this.defaultValue);
                            }
                            System.out.println("REGEX:"+s.toString());
                            s.executeUpdate();
                            columnsAdded = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            checkInvalidInfo(tablesFound, columnsAdded, "All the matching tables already had that column");
        } catch (InvalidArgumentsNumberException | SQLException | InvalidInfoException | DatabaseException e) {
            throw new CustomChangeException("Error enabling trigger: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes. You construct the SQL manually without sanitization, so by the time you call prepareStatement, it's too late. What if `this.getColumnName()` returned `''; DROP TABLE blahblah...`

Comment: Is there any way I can prevent it?I do really need the parameters to be passed by the XML File

Comment: So in this case I don't really need PreparedStatement and can use Statement instead?

Comment: I don't know if this is viable, but for the example you gave, would it be safe if I verify if the value of the variables is a single word?

Comment: Of course. Writing your own perfectly functioning SQL injection protection is certainly possible, but it's also risky. If it's sufficient for you to check that a String contains A-Z characters, that's sufficiently simple that I wouldn't reject it from a code review. The more complex your custom validation is, the higher chance it will contain a bug that undermines the entire protection.

Comment: @Michael so in this case PreparedStatement is not necessary ? With Statement I don't need to instantiate a new object everytime I want to execute a query . Is there any other vantage on using PreparedStatement besides security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether it is an SQL injection vulnerability will depend on where that XML file comes from.

If programmers are authoring such files, then you do not have an SQL injection problem.  Yes, it is *possible* to concatenate dangerous things, but it’s no more of a risk than a developer writing dangerous things directly into the code.

However, if the XML files come from end users, or from other services, or from files that other people or services are permitted to modify, then they should be considered potentially dangerous, and your code would be at risk of an SQL injection attack.

Since all of your concatenated values are actually identifiers (column names and a data type), rather than values, you probably will be safe if you check that they consist only of alphanumeric characters:

```
if (!getColumnName().matches("\\p{AlNum}+")) {
    throw new CustomChangeException(
        "Invalid column name: \"" + getColumnName() + "\"");
}
if (!after.matches("\\p{AlNum}+")) {
    throw new CustomChangeException(
        "Invalid 'after' column name: \"" + after + "\"");
}
if (!getColumnType().matches("\\p{AlNum}+")) {
    throw new CustomChangeException(
        "Invalid column type: \"" + getColumnType() + "\"");
}
```

Comment: alphanumeric excludes spaces right? This way the user can't send more than one word . This was my basic idea for protection

Comment: Correct, {AlNum} is only A-Z, a-z, and 0-9.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix.

Comment: Since PreparedStatement is pretty useless because I am receiving values from a file ,should I switch to Statement? This way I wouldn't need to always instanciate a new object

Comment: There is no harm in using a PreparedStatement.

Comment: also, shouldn' I make the verification in defaultValue too? Because if the value sent can be for example "ABC;DROP TABLE asdds"

Comment: No.  PreparedStatement.setString handles that for you.  Only the string concatenations need sanitization.

Comment: Normally, no, it does not.  You can use `"(?U)\\p{AlNum}+"` or `"[\\p{L}\\p{N}]+"` for that.

Comment: Is that a regex? I found this one that allows letters,numbers and lowercases. I think that if I stick with english it should be enough `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$`

Comment: They are indeed regular expressions.  Actually, to make sure you match decomposed accented letters, you should use `"[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{M}]+"`.  Note that `^` and `$` are unnecessary, since String.matches is always an anchored match.

Comment: That's a really confusing regex. Does L mean letters,N Numbers?

Comment: `\\p{…}` can refer to a [Unicode character category](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values).  See [the Pattern documentation’s examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#unicode).  So, yes, that regex means any letter (L) or number (N) or mark/accent (M), repeated one or more times.

Comment: So if I want to add _ to it it would be `"[\\p{L}\\p{N}\\p{M}\\_]+"`?

Comment: Yes, although you don’t need the backslashes.  Just adding `_` is sufficient.